# API script to save google sheet to excel in defined folder under google drive

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm now to API script, I need a script to help in saving a google sheet to excel format with the same name under the same google drive folder that I can run it regularly of schedule it.

I know that there is download as an option but I need to automate the process.

Thanks in advance 
Osama

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: function saveAsXls() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var thisSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var id = thisSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("https://Added my drive address")
  var ssName = ss.getName();
  DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(ssName,destFolder)
}

Answer (score 0):

### Retrieve the exportlink with the Drive API and create a new file from blob

For this [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) and proceed as following:

```
function saveAsXls() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Added my drive address") 
  var ssName = ss.getName(); 
  var url = Drive.Files.get(ss.getId()).exportLinks["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"];  
  var  blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    },
  });  
  destFolder.createFile(blob).setName(ssName);
}
```

**For understanding please refer to the following references:**

- [Exportlinks](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files)
- [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getAs(String))
- [Url fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch)
- [Create file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob)